# How to recover a stopped docker container which ran out of space?

Tags: docker

I've got a docker container that reached the default 10GB limit, and now I cannot start it anymore. This is the error I receive:

> Error response from daemon: Cannot start container dfc: setup mount
>   namespace can't create pivot_root dir , error mkdir
>   /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/dfc2df0ba006762d44e13a3fe12b113a970ca7d91a530a8af1e82178d22f5608/rootfs/.pivot_root753727542:
>   no space left on device 2015/01/12 15:32:58 Error: failed to start one
>   or more containers

There's a [blog post](http://jpetazzo.github.io/2014/01/29/docker-device-mapper-resize/) explaining how to increase the size of the container past the 10GB limit, but it seens to assume the container is running. In my case, It's stopped and I can't find the correct device in /dev/mapper.

Is there any way to increase the container size, so I can recover access to my container?

Comment: Did you try to copy files to outside container and run another container mapping container files by host server?

Answer (score 1):

It is not trivial but possible. I did it once on RedHat7. It will probably not work with older versions of Centos/Redhat.

I explained it in this [post](https://esalagea.wordpress.com/2016/02/16/recover-a-docker-container-which-ran-out-of-space-with-device-mapper/).

Basically, you perform these steps:

- Save the container as an image, using docker commit
- Save the new image as a tar file on disk, using docker save
- Reconfigure the default space per container, as explained in this [post](https://esalagea.wordpress.com/2015/10/05/increase-disk-size-of-docker-containers-when-using-device-mapper/)
- In the previous step will loose all local images and containers, but you have saved your image as a tar file on disk.
- Load the image you previousley saved, using docker load
- Run a new container from the just loaded image, using docker run