# Docker: System error: can’t create pivot_root dir

Tags: ubuntu, docker

I've got stardog running on an Ubuntu 15.04 container. After a period over a week or so of normal operation I have had the following exception occur twice now.

```
Cannot start container f8fc55f1872cd72f1eaad8be57ed5536172d55d1a80fae46812a91d1a022cf77: 
    [8] System error: can't create pivot_root dir , error mkdir /var/lib/docker/devicemapper
    /mnt/f8fc55f1872cd72f1eaad8be57ed5536172d55d1a80fae46812a91d1a022cf77/rootfs
    /.pivot_root580962379: no space left on device
```

/var is on a partition with 165G available so the drive has plenty of free room.

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-15-150 ~]$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1      394G  229G  165G  59% /
```

Any ideas as to what causes this error and how to resolve it?

docker info currently.. be aware I've already delete the container and image and rebuilt at this point so this is misleading..

```
Containers: 13
Images: 223
Server Version: 1.9.1
Storage Driver: devicemapper
 Pool Name: docker-202:1-263462-pool
 Pool Blocksize: 65.54 kB
 Base Device Size: 10.74 GB
 Backing Filesystem: 
 Data file: /dev/loop0
 Metadata file: /dev/loop1
 Data Space Used: 11.32 GB
 Data Space Total: 107.4 GB
 Data Space Available: 96.06 GB
 Metadata Space Used: 13.07 MB
 Metadata Space Total: 2.147 GB
 Metadata Space Available: 2.134 GB
```

Thanks
Conteh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 no space left on device
```

Your Harddrive is full :) Plain and simple => It cant create new containers.

As added in the comment, the output of

docker info

is what counts here as docker is using its own filesystem.
To resize it you need to wipe out the existing docker file system ( **Backup Volume Content if you need any of it still :)** )

Then restart the docker daemon with the option

```
 docker daemon --storage-opt dm.loopdatasize=200G
```

or whatever you want to allocate to it :)

Comment: ,, I added information about the size of the drive into my question.

Comment: Docker runs in its own filesystem.
Check the output of
`docker info`

Comment: Okay I added the docker info into the question..how do you increase the limit?

Comment: Okay it looks like https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/daemon/#storage-driver-options has the instructions for changing the sizes.

Comment: As far as I know re-sizing itself is not an option unless you're running thinpool, which you shouldn't be doing in the first place in production due to performance reasons.

Comment: Okay assuming I don't mind deleting all my images and starting fresh. Is there any setting other than the thinpool that allows a container to have more space? I've read on another [post from 2012](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27907689/how-to-recover-a-stopped-docker-container-which-ran-out-of-space?rq=1) that there is a 10GB limit for a container,, do you know if that is still true?

Comment: https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/14709 => no :)

Though frankly, you should potentially try and not let your container sizes get out of hand and use volumes for huge amounts of data.
Containers should be ephemeral, otherwise backups become a pain, believe me :)

Comment: Yeah I'm using volumes for the db data.. I think in hindsight what happens is the db would get corrupted during a unexpected ungraceful shutdown and move the corrupted db's out of the volumes into some other folder to help me out :) Maybe I can specify where that corrupted directory is. Thanks @Armin